# Content element gallery messing up everything

Tags: templates, content-elements

We are using content element module version(1.6.4) along with EE Version(2.9.2),and when using gallery tag in the template the output is simply showing other tags instead of information, please check the output

[image]

And we used the expression in template like this

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="nieuws"}     
      {title}
      {nieuws_description}
            {editor}
                {value}
            {/editor}
            {gallery}
            {if images}
                {images}
                    Thumbnail: <img src="{thumb}" /><br />
                    Original: <img src="{image}" /><br />
                    Image type: {extension}<br />
                    Image size: {size}<br />
                    Caption: {caption}<br />
                {/images}
            {/if}
        {/gallery}
        {/nieuws_description}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So basically there is a something wrong in gallery tag because if we remove it from template it works fine.

Please help!

Regards
Nisar

Comment: Have you tried updating to the current version (1.7.1) to see if that changes anything?

Comment: Also, have you tried without the {if images} {/if} to see it that makes a difference?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried all that but the issue was something else, the issue was "I was using a field with name "gallery" in one of my channel,after renaming it everything back to normal"

Comment: @NisarUddin Please post the details of what fixed your issue below as an answer and accept it as your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if custom field with short_name "nieuws_description" already exists in custom fields settings.

Comment: My bad that I was using a field with name "gallery" in one of my channel,after renaming it everything back to normal :)